# Polynomial division proof

Tags: polynomials

What first? I don't know where should I begin: $a$ and $b$ is integer and $W$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients.

> Prove that: $a-b$ divides  $W(a) - W(b)$

Comment: yes, I need a proof

Comment: Hint: Let $g(x)=x^k$. First show that $a-b$ divides $g(a)-g(b)$, that is, $a^k-b^k$.

Answer (score 4):

Fix $b\in\Bbb Z$. Note that $P(X):=W(X)-W(b)$ is an integer polynomial with $P(b)=0$. Hence $P(X)=(X-b)\cdot Q(X)$ and then $P(a)=(a-b)\cdot Q(a)$.