# Why is $f(x)\equiv f(x+2k)\pmod k$ for$ f(x)=x(x+1)/2 + c.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratics

I came across this in a programming contest:

`f(x)%k = f(x+2k)%k  for f(x)=x(x+1)/2 + c`

I first thought  that  this is a property of Harmonic numbers only but after trying a few things, I found out that

`f(x)%k = f(x+k*a*b)%k  for f(x)= x/a + x^2/b + c`

My question is how can this be derived intuitively?

Which branch of Mathematics does this fall into  ? I have a hint that this is number theories, but is there a particular concepts/topic that programming contests assume that contesters should know as basics/foundation?

Is there a more general form of this theorem?  Beyond quadratic? (and if it has a name, what it is called? )

Domain: a, b, c, k and x are Positive integers

Comment: Is $k$ a non-zero integer? For the second equation with $f(x) = \frac xa + \frac{x^2}b + c$, does that `%k` (or $\bmod k$) operation accept non-integers? (Which is fine, I guess)

Comment: K is only positive integers

Comment: How did you "find out' the second expression? The ‘%‘ operator only applies to integers, and what you wrote is not true in general.

Comment: Are you aware that for polynomials with integer coefficients,  if $ a \equiv b \pmod{k}$, then $g(a) \equiv g(b) \pmod{k}$?

Comment: For the second equation, how are $a$, $b$ and $k$ related? $f(x+2ab) - f(x)$ doesn't seem to definitely be a multiple of $k$.

Comment: Hint (for the first one): $g(x) = 2f(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients, so [$a-b \,|\, g(a) - g(b)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1758221/polynomial-division-proof) for all integers $a,b$.

Comment: I might be wrong in the second equation, I used desmos and played around with the coefficient of the quadratic function f(x) and noticed that equation 2) stands true if we multiply the denominators of the x^2 and x together.  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dgkns63zn7

Comment: For the second equation, you seem to be considering $f(x+kab)\bmod k$ in your Desmos graph, not $f(x+2ab)\bmod k$ on the right hand side.

Comment: @peterwhy you're right. I made a mistake while writing the question. My apology for the confusion. Question updated

Answer (score 0):

$f(x+2k)\equiv \frac{(x+2k)(x+2k+1)}{2}+c \pmod k$

$\equiv \frac{x^2+2kx+x+2kx+4k^2+2k}{2}+c \pmod k$

$\equiv k(2x+2k+1)+\frac{x^2+x}{2}+c \pmod k$

$\equiv \frac{x(x+1)}{2}+c \pmod k$

$\equiv f(x) \pmod k$